# Как можно сгенерировать события касания к объекту 'Item' на графической сцене 'QGraphicsScene'

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Есть у меня графическая сцена 'QGraphicsScene' на которой рисую состояния  элементов управления (ну так сказать визуальный контроль), приложил рисунок для наглядности. Состояния отдельного элемента управления представляется в виде квадратика с рамкой (обрати внимания на квадратик с номером '000'). Цвет рамки и внутренней части квадратика разные. Исходя из цветовой гаммы можно определить в каком состоянии находиться элемент управления. Под элементом  управления можно понимать реле. Замкнуто разомкнуто. Или датчик температуры. На нарисованной мной сцене квадратики получились маленькие и не очень удобно лазить в 'help' чтобы посмотреть, что означает цветовая гамма определённого элемента управления.
Поэтому хочу добавить возможность вызова всплывающего окна с описанием состояния элемента управления. Но как сделать не знаю. Поэтому и спрашиваю у знающих людей. Скажу сразу компьютер тормозной на arm ядрt.
Qt 4.7.8.

Как вижу решение, но не знаю как сделать в qt:

*1. Нужно сгенерировать событие (вызвать метод, вектор) в котором я получу информацию о каком квадратики пользователь хочет узнать информацию что-то типа 'event(number rect)' могу заблуждаться. По номеру rect буду обращаться к структуре данных содержащая в себе информацию о объекте.
2. Нарисовать сплывающие окно в центе экрана с информацией о объекте.
3. По нажатию на кнопку "ОК" (кнопка "OK" находиться на сплывающем окне) закрыть всплывающие окно.*

Думаю это все.
Элементы квадратики не должны двигаться на экране.

Что сделано:
В конструкторе main .c

```
       graphicsScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      statebalanser = new StateBalanser(i);
      statebalanser->setPos((i * 54) % 540, (i / 10) * 42);
      graphicsScene->addItem(statebalanser);
   }
   graphicsScene->setSceneRect(-4,-4,544,1104);
   ui->graphicsView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
   ui->graphicsView->setInteractive(true);
   ui->graphicsView->setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView::NoAnchor);
   ui->graphicsView->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::NoAnchor);
   ui->graphicsView->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::SmartViewportUpdate);
   ui->graphicsView->setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView::DontSavePainterState, true);
   ui->graphicsView->setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
   ui->graphicsView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
   ui->graphicsView->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
   ui->graphicsView->setScene(graphicsScene);
```

StateBalanser.h

```
    #ifndef STATEBALANSER_H
#define STATEBALANSER_H
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <memorymap.h>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFontDatabase>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>

class StateBalanser : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    StateBalanser(int num);

public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);

    void StateBalance();

    void setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2);

    void setColorText(QColor text);

    void setFontText(QFont fontText);

private:
    int number;

private:
    QPainterPath _painterPath;

    QRectF _intersect;

    QColor _fillColorState;

    QColor _fillColorModeWork;

    QColor _fillColorText;

    QFont  _fontText;

    QString numberRect;

public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    QPainterPath shape() const;
};

#endif // STATEBALANSER_H
```

StateBalanser.c

```
    #include "statebalanser.h"

StateBalanser::StateBalanser(int num) :
    number(num)
{
    setColorState(DisabledBalancer,StateDisabled);

    StateBalanser::StateBalance();

    StateBalanser::setColorText(Qt::black);

    int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/liquidcr.ttf");

    QFont font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());

    font.setPointSize(12);

    StateBalanser::setFontText(font);

    _painterPath = shape();

    numberRect = QString().sprintf("%03d", number + 1);
}


void StateBalanser::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->fillRect(boundingRect(), _fillColorModeWork);

    painter->fillRect(_intersect, _fillColorState);

    painter->drawPath(_painterPath);

    painter->setFont(_fontText);

    painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, numberRect );
}


void StateBalanser::StateBalance()
{
  _intersect = boundingRect().intersected(QRectF(3, 3, 44, 32));
}


void StateBalanser::setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2)
{ 
   switch(value_2)
   {
   case StopBalancer :        _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#000000") ;
      break;

   case ChargeBalancer :      _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#0000ff") ;
      break;

   case DischargeBalancer :   _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ff0000") ;
      break;

   case EsrBalancer :         _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#32CD32") ;
     break;

   case DisconnectBalancer :  _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#000000") ;
      break;

   case DisabledBalancer :    _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;

   default :                  _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;
   }

   switch(value_1)
   {
   case StateGood :      _fillColorState =  QColor("#99FF99") ;
      break;

  case  StateFiftyFifty: _fillColorState =  QColor("#FFFF66") ;
     break;

  case StateFault :      _fillColorState =  QColor("#FF9999")  ;
     break;

  case StateDisconnect:  _fillColorState =  QColor("#999999") ;
     break;

  case StateMeasurement: _fillColorState =  QColor("#a2c8d6") ;
     break;

  case StateDisabled:    _fillColorState =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;

  default :              _fillColorState =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;
   }
}


void StateBalanser::setColorText(QColor text)
{
    _fillColorText =  QColor(text);
}


void StateBalanser::setFontText(QFont fontText)
{
    _fontText = fontText;
}


QRectF StateBalanser::boundingRect() const
{
   return QRectF(0, 0, 49, 37);
}


QPainterPath StateBalanser::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;

    path.addRect(boundingRect());

    return path;
}
```

Вот такой вид окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вид графической сцены.

Comment: Если правильно понял поставленный вопрос, то обычной всплывающей подсказки должно хватить, для того, чтобы информировать пользователя об состоянии объекта.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setToolTip

Comment: Мне же нужно вызвать событие (метод) в котором я смогу получить номер квадратика. И исходя из номера квадратика выдать информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно решить вопрос и другим способом.

0. Реализовываем обработчик двойного клика мыши на графическую сцену - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent.
   PS: Чтобы этот метод реализовать нужно наследовать графическую сцену.
1. Вызываем метод для получения выделенного объекта графической сцены - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#selectedItems.
2. Преобразовываем указатель к типу StateBalanser - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#qgraphicsitem_cast.

Это основные методы для решения поставленной задачи.